# .docx stored in SQL Server results in "there was an error opening the file"

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ms-word

I am working on a legacy Windows desktop application written in VB.net 4.0 with a SQL Server 2005 database.
The application generates reports based on Word templates which are stored in the database.
There is an admin section that allows new Word report templates (.docx) to be loaded into the database in case there are some changes to the text in the report.
The admin form allows new files to be added, or existing ones deleted or updated.  When adding a new file it asks for a code (text) which is used as the primary key for the file in the database lookup table it is stored in.  It also allows a file to be selected and opened from the database so it can be viewed.

The following behavior can be consistently reproduced:
A new .docx file can be added with a new code (primary key).
That file can be successfully opened.
If any existing file is updated with a new .docx, any attempt to open will fail with the error message "there was an error opening the file" in Word.
If that file's record is deleted, and the same file is added with a new code (PK) then it can open successfully.
If the same file (or any .docx file) is added using the same code (PK) as the deleted file, it will appear to write to DB ok, but any attempt to open the file will fail with the same error message as above.

The .docx files that cannot be opened are one byte longer than when they can be successfully opened.
The .docx files that cannot be opened by Word can still be open as an archive (with 7zip for example) and the file contents appear to be the same.

Overwriting an existing file, or reusing a deleted file's code (PK) with any other file type (including .doc) will work fine.  Only .docx files are causing problems; which is a shame as .docx files are required because the report generation is achieved by manipulating the Word document contents with OpenXML code.

Here's the code that inserts the file to the database:

```
Private Sub btnInsert_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles     btnInsert.Click
    Dim sName As String = InputBox("What is the name of this Resource")
    If (sName.Length > 0) Then
        Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
        With ofd
            .CheckFileExists = True
            .ShowReadOnly = False
            .Filter = "All Files|*.*"
            If (.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK) Then
                Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                Dim docByte As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}
                fs.Read(docByte, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length))
                fs.Close()

                Dim FileType As String = Path.GetExtension(.FileName).ToLower

                Dim conn As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlInsert, conn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", sName)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bytes", docByte)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Types", FileType)

                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()

                MsgBox("Saved to DB")
                Dim li As ListViewItem = lvwResource.Items.Add(sName)
                li.SubItems.Add(FileType)

                docByte = Nothing
                fs.Dispose()
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

And the code that retrieves:

```
Private Sub btnOpen_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOpen.Click

    Dim sName As String = lvwResource.SelectedItems(0).Text
    Dim sType As String = lvwResource.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
    Dim fileName As String = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Path.GetTempPath, sName, sType)

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlSelect, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", sName)

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)

    Dim docByte() As Byte = dt.Rows(0)(1)
    Dim fs As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
    fs.Write(docByte, 0, Convert.ToInt32(docByte.Length))
    fs.Dispose()

    Try
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Question, "Unknown Resource Type")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Some further details:  Workstations are Windows XP Sp3 with Microsoft Office 2003 SP3, server is Server 2003 Standard edition SP2, db is SQL Server 2005 SP2.
It is a large organisation and I have no influence over their outdated software.

Comment: (1) Please post the code you are using to store/retrieve your document objects. (2) what happens when you extract a .docx to a disk file instead of opening it directly in Word? E.g. is it still a .docx? Is it the same length as the file you saved? Shorter? Longer? Are all extracted .docx files the same length? Can you still unzip them, and if so, what do they contain?

Comment: bibadia - I have updated the post to include the extra detail you have requested.  In answer to your question (2) The retrieval code writes the file to the temp directory and open it from there.  It appears in the directory as a .docx file, but is one byte longer than the original file, according to the file **Size** property (**Size on disk** is identical both times).  The retrieved file can be opened with 7zip and all contents appear normal.

Comment: What if you (1) explicitly fs.Close() and (2) for .docx file type, write one less byte?

Comment: (1) explicitly adding fs.Close() did not make a difference; and (2) writing one less byte for .docx file type did not make a difference.  :(

Comment: Thanks for your time, bibadia.  A solution has been found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, a solution has been found.
Many thanks are due to Franklin Chan on the MSDN forum for his time and patience in helping me.

The error was in the update code, which I never posted here (my bad!).

When reading the file to update and existing record I had the following code:

```
Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(.FileName, FileMode.Open)
Dim img As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length) {}
fs.Read(img, 0, fs.Length)
fs.Close()
```

I was doing it the right way in the Insert sub, funnily enough.  The correct syntax is:

```
Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim img As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}
fs.Read(img, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length))
fs.Close()
```

Another important step that was missing was to clear the temp file before extracting from the database and opening, so adding:

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(fileName) = True Then
    System.IO.File.Delete(fileName)
End If
```

to the btnOpen() code.